# It is not the case, however, that the XXX can do LLL

Tags: word-choice, negation, inversion

There is a phrase that from an article:

> It is not the case, however, that XXX can always be constructed using
>   LLL.

Can I interpret as: XXX can always be constructed using LLL; or XXX can't always be constructed using LLL?

Comment: The title seems inconsistent with the question.

Answer (score 5):

Try to break down the sentence into two parts to make it simpler:

> It is not the case, however,

and

> That XXX can always be constructed using LLL

Sentence 2 says that XXX can always be constructed using LLL and sentence 1 tells you that this is not always the case.

So your second interpretation is correct: *XXX can't always be constructed using LL*L.